# Serially Execute Spark Processes in one Program

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data pipeline where I must perform many small incremental operations on *distinct* final sinks. Think, take one huge input dataframe, split it up, and write the contents to many small separate tables/buckets.

I wish to do this serially within a single Spark process, as the overhead in initial processing is computationally heavy. In this example can identify a series of `target` actions to loop over, and loop over them.

Every combination I come up with has the *driver* doing all the work for the serial operations. It eventually runs out of memory and dies. Though if I copy/paste each command independently into a program, it properly runs across the cluster.

```
val df = (some complicated query, returning lots of data)
val someOtherDf = (something time consuming, huge df)

// Some large set of small tasks - can come from anywhere
val targets = someOtherDf.select("a_column").distinct.collect.toSeq

targets.foreach(target => process(target)) // this appears to only happen within the driver


// This is fairly "cheap", and must be repeated many times. 
def process(df1, df2, someValue) = {
  df1.where("column" === lit(someValue)).join(df2, df1.col("joinColumn") === df2.col("joinColumn")).writeTo("someTable").createOrReplace
}
```

Is there a way to serially execute some process on a dataframe within a single Spark context?

Comment: Could you specify what `targets` is doing here and how large it is? It seems you're not using it in the code. Also, where is `values` defined, what is its type?

Comment: Fixed the example, `values` is the same as `targets`. My mistake. Say `targets` can be 100k items. Say, it is a list of user names from a table, where the outcome of this program is a brand new table for every user we observe.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why do you want to write to 100k different tables? I can't think of a good reason why to do this, maybe if you explain we'll be able to give you a better way to handle this.

Comment: Let's call it a business requirement more than a technical one. For example, pretend it is a version of fine-grained-access control where people can access data within tables, but we need to limit the rows they can access (but can't enforce some row-level permission). Or it is a scale concern where 1 table is too big. Regardless, I'm interested in knowing if I can use typical program flow controls within a spark process without it confining all work within that flow control to just the driver. Certainly seems doable.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know what gets executed on the driver, and what gets executed on the executor to answer this question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77364995/15405732) discusses which operations happen on the driver, and which happen on the executor. The short version of it is:

- Distributed operations on distributed datasets (RDDs, DataFrames, Datasets) happen on the executor.

  - In your case, the first two queries handling your big datasets take place on the executors. And also the underlying operation (there must be a syntax error in your `join`, missing the second table but it does not matter for this answer):

```
df1.where("column" === lit(someValue)).join("joinColumn").writeTo("someTable").createOrReplace
```

- All the rest happens on the driver.

Now, it seems you're trying to use Spark in a way it's not really intended for. If you're under the impression that all of the work happens on the driver, it means that in your `foreach` loop (over which you loop 100k times) has much more work in all of the overhead related things (making sure a table exists, creating it, looping over your list, ...) than in the actual filtering of your table and writing away the records related to the current loop iteration.

#### What would I recommend to get over this issue?

Going from most recommended to less recommended:

1. As I said in the comments, I would avoid doing this. You're setting yourself up for a lot of technical debt like this. You will have bad performance for both writing (as you're already feeling now) and reading and it will be a mess. Spark is a big data tool that can easily handle HUGE tables so working with huge tables should not be an issue. If you need this for access control there are other ways of solving this. But I understand you want to explore this idea, so adding some more options here.
2. If you really want to have some kind of "separation" of your tables, you could try partitioning when writing away to disk. So instead of having your `foreach` loop, you would have one big `join` and `saveAsTable` like so:

```
df1.join(df2, "joinColumn").partitionBy("column").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("someTable")
```

2. Continuing on this point, this will give you a disk layout that separates the files from all of your distinct values in `column` from eachother. I would not necessarily recommend this, because your `column` column is of high cardinality (100k) so this will give your performance hits. You will get some "physical" separation between the tables though. You'll also be able to read in files differently and could even give different permissions to different partitions.
3. Continue as you're doing but give more resources to your driver by increasing `spark.driver.memory` when running your program. Your executor resources will probably be pretty insignificant. Doing this moves you away from distributed computing in the direction of serial computing so using something like [polars](https://www.pola.rs/) instead of Spark might give you better results.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. As I said this isn't a spark or a data concern - I know spark can handle big data. I need to write a big table into many many small ones (I know. This is not ideal). I'm not talking about partitioning a single dataset, I need wholly isolated small subsets of the data. 

> If you're under the impression that all of the work happens on the driver,

I am because I can see that my cluster is idle, and there are no distributed tasks/operations actually doing the heavy lifting within the `foreach` loop. The driver is doing everything. Hence. My question here. :-)

Comment: Fair enough! I'm surprised that even the writing of your dataset to a table does not take place on your executors. Can you share a fully reproducible example that I can execute on my machine? We'll figure this out!